# How to limit user login to specific machine?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, network-programming

I am developing web application in ASP.NET and C#,

in which a user should get login access from a specific machine. It will not allowed for the user to login from another machine.

**How to limit the user by a specific machine?**

Can I do this in ASP.NET, C# or in a Java applet?

Comment: Duplicate of [Web application where users can only register and access from one PC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564930/web-application-where-users-can-only-register-and-access-from-one-pc). Abhishek, this question is essentially identical to your earlier one. Either improve that one, or ask a different question.

Comment: @Michael, that question is beyond improvement. :)

Comment: @bzlm: Maybe. Posting an identical question isn't the right path, though.

Comment: @Michael, let's help Abhishek remove the old question then. :)

Comment: @Abhishek, why do you want to do this? What does it matter to you whether a user accesses your web application from multiple machines?

Comment: Hello @bzlm , In our application there is Reseller & workers. workers can not access accounts from own PC. If workers leaved the job at that time Reseller doesnt know. and Reseller have credits to share amount. I want that workers should not access their login in the system from another machine..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than locking access down to a specific MAC address, I'd recommend using certificate-based authentication. Have a trusted administrator install a certificate on the user's machine (in the local machine store) and ensure it's not marked as exportable.

This article may help in terms of setup.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315588

MAC addresses can be easily spoofed and only offer a degree of obfuscation.

Comment: Hello @Steve_Morgan, How I can do with certificate based authentication.?